# What may cause these horizontal lines on my monitor?

Tags: drivers, display, troubleshooting

I have two screenshots than can explain my problem much better than words. The lines on my LCD monitor are always at different places, flickering on and off.
They are more pronounced when I watch videos in the browser. Reinstalling videocard drivers didn't help.

I believe it's videocard related. What do I do now to pinpoint the cause?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm actually surprised that they are visible on screenshots. That suggests it's a software issue. Screenshots show what OS was intending to draw, so in case of GPU/display failures they look completely fine.

Comment: That noise in the video could be crap in the source or noise introduced in the process of getting it to you.  You can also get that from a strong nearby radio signal, especially one being illegally boosted (well illegal in the US).